# Binding and converters for unbound window

Tags: wpf, vb.net, validation, idataerrorinfo

I have a window with a number of controls which are not bound to anything else. However, I would like to apply some window-specific validation. I think I can do this by implementing `IDataErrorInfo` on the window; and either implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged` for the indivual controls/properties as well, or exposing dependency properties on the window and binding to those dependency properties (which would also allow me to leverage exisiting ValueConverters on these controls). Is this advisable? What are the downsides of doing this?

This is what I am considering (XAML):

```
<Window xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    x:Class="winInitialContact" x:Name="UC">
  <StackPanel>
    <Label Content="From" />
    <TextBox Text="{Binding FromTime, ElementName=UC, Converter={StaticResource TimeConverter}, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}" />
    <Label Content="To" />
    <TextBox Text="{Binding ToTime, ElementName=UC, Converter={StaticResource TimeConverter}, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}" />
  </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

and code:

```
Imports System.ComponentModel

Class MainWindow
    Implements IDataErrorInfo
    Implements INotifyPropertyChanged

    Shared ReadOnly FromTimeProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("FromTime", GetType(TimeSpan?), GetType(MainWindow), New FrameworkPropertyMetadata(Nothing, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault, Sub(s, e) DirectCast(s, MainWindow).RaisePropertyChanged("FromTime")))
    Property FromTime As TimeSpan?
        Get
            Return GetValue(FromTimeProperty)
        End Get
        Set(value As TimeSpan?)
            SetValue(FromTimeProperty, value)
        End Set
    End Property

    Shared ReadOnly ToTimeProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("ToTime", GetType(TimeSpan?), GetType(MainWindow), New FrameworkPropertyMetadata(Nothing, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault, Sub(s, e) DirectCast(s, MainWindow).RaisePropertyChanged("ToTime")))
    Property ToTime As TimeSpan?
        Get
            Return GetValue(ToTimeProperty)
        End Get
        Set(value As TimeSpan?)
            SetValue(ToTimeProperty, value)
        End Set
    End Property

    Public ReadOnly Property [Error] As String Implements IDataErrorInfo.Error
        Get
            Return Nothing
        End Get
    End Property

    Default Public ReadOnly Property Item(columnName As String) As String Implements IDataErrorInfo.Item
        Get
            Select Case columnName
                Case "FromTime"
                    If Not FromTime.HasValue Then Return "Missing from time"
                Case "ToTime"
                    If Not ToTime.HasValue Then Return "Missing end time"
            End Select
            Return Nothing
        End Get
    End Property

    Public Event PropertyChanged(sender As Object, e As PropertyChangedEventArgs) Implements INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged

    Sub RaisePropertyChanged(propName As String)
        RaiseEvent PropertyChanged(Me, New PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName))
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Have you checked out `ValidationRule`? Seems like it would solve your issue and it wouldn't be a weird approach.

Comment: @Jim Except that I wouldn't be able to use the existing ValueConverters.

Comment: Are you talking in general or in your situation? ValidationRules can be combined with ValueConverters

Comment: @Jim How can I apply a `ValidationRule` directly to the window without binding?

Comment: You should post some code, it's hard to get a feel of what you're asking without seeing.